# I'm good at it - pseudo passive voice request

Tags: phrase-request

This question is derived from [another one](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/28364/19307) that has recently appeared in the Spanish Stack Site.

There, OP has translated a Spanish sentence into English and it's a good translation but it's not an accurate one.

The sentence in Spanish is: Se me da **bien**
It can be translated as: I'm **good** at it.

But in the original Spanish version "it" is the omitted subject, this has been "reversed" in the English version where the first person is the subject.
How can I express that in English, forcing the thing that **I'm good at** as the subject?

I can only come with **that's my thing**, a sentence that has already been discussed [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/51126/meaning-of-what-is-your-thing) but notice that this expression lacks an adjective or adverb, it doesn't explicitly states if I'm **good** nor if I always do something **well** or **wrong** [*modus operandi, a behavioural pattern*].

I'm looking for something like: [subject - it] [verb] [adjective - good] [first person pronoun - me?]

Comment: You could simply say _Good at it_ as a reply to praise or else say _It's my forte_

Comment: Well, "Good at it" is just "I'm good at it" omitting the subject. "It's my forte" is a good approximation.

Comment: I'm sure there are a lot of _slangy_ expressions with the similar meaning but that's not my forte )))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Translation from one language to another is not merely a substitution of words. As some languages are constructed differently, an accurate translation conveys the *intended meaning*, not the structure. Other *Romance languages* may allow you to translate from Spanish and keep the structure, but that is not necessarily possible with a *Germanic language* such as English.

If you were to omit the subject in English and simply say "I'm good" this would not be well understood, as this expression is used idiomatically by native English speakers to mean either "I am well", and sometimes in American English to decline an offer of something, akin to saying "no thank you". So, I would have to agree that "*I'm good at it*" is probably the best translation of the Spanish phrase "*se me da bien*".

You could reverse the English phrase and say...

> It is what I am good at.

... but this implies that "it" is the *only* thing you are good at, whereas "I'm good at it" does not exclude the possibility that you are good at other things too.

To remove that implication you could say:

> It is something I am good at.